# Disable output using battery protection IC

Tags: battery-charging, schematics, battery-operated

I am trying to design a pretty simple battery pack for a project, I'm relatively new to designing circuits, and I had a couple of questions I was hoping to get some advice on.

The circuit I'm designing takes two 18650 cells in series and steps them down to a 5 V 1 A output and 5 V 5 A output. It also charges the pack and has [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ablic-inc/S-8252AAG-M6T1U/6121446) 2 cell protection IC.

The circuit uses two boards I bought online (one for USB-C charging and balancing the cells and one for the 5 V 5 A output) because I don't know how to design those parts yet.

Here is the schematic:
[image: full schematic]

The main part I have questions about is the protection IC in the middle. That part of the schematic is directly copied from the datasheet's example.

Here is the example from the datasheet I copied:
[image: example schematic from datasheet]

So here are my questions:
What's the best way to add an on-off switch to disable the output? I want a switch that turns off discharge. I was trying to think of some way to use the protection IC to switch off the discharge FET for me instead of having another FET connected to a switch to turn off the power. I want to do this with as few additional components as possible, as the PCB is already cramped. I was thinking a switch across one of the cells connected to the discharge FET, but the [FETS](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IPD090N03LGATMA1/1785601) have a V_GS of 2.2 V, so would the 3-4.2 V from a cell be too much? I also thought that I could try to manipulate one of the IC's cell inputs so the IC thinks the cell is undervoltage, and so it turns off the discharge FET for me, or if curring power to the IC with a switch would turn off the FETs.

My other question also involves this IC. [The charging board](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256804918648817.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.fa5f38daOFm0IO&mp=1&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa) I have comes with overvoltage protection and balancing for 2 cells, so I have it hooked up directly to the cells instead of going threw the protection IC for charging. I think this means the charge FET the protection IC is connected to is useless, as it will never turn off charging. Can I remove this FET and run the circuit with only one FET for discharge control? I know it will affect the overcurrent threshold, but I can fix that with a different FET or a shunt resistor. My concern is if the IC's charge control pin is floating, will that screw with the protection IC.

Also, if you see anything wrong with my schematic, please let me know, I'm not 100% confident in it right now.

Thank you, and it's my first time posting here so if I did something wrong, take it easy on me lol.

Comment: Your first mistake is that the load is still connected to the battery while it's being charged. That can confuse the charger and lead to overcharging, which can cause fire or explosion with Li-ion batteries.